# Como posso fazer um SELECT para mostrar maior numero de pontos

Tags: php

Bom é assim, a minha dúvida é bastante simples. Pretendo fazer um select a * de uma tabela no meu banco de dados, mas tenho 2 prioridades.

Primeiro pretendo mostrar todos os resultados por ordem onde os que têm a coluna pontos com valor maior apareçam primeiro.

Caso essa coluna pontos seja igual para duas linhas da minha tabela, pretendo que os que tenham maior valor na coluna DG, apareça em primeiro.

Como poderei fazer isto?

Obrigado.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABELA ORDER BY pontos desc, dg desc` já tentou isso.? se não dar certo, porque eu arrisquei, postei o layout da sua tabela, a estrutura?

Comment: Muito Obrigado Virgilio era isso mesmo!

Comment: Faz uma resposta para ele marcar @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Oi @Ricardo, olha se você quiser fazer tudo bem, mas, eu acho muito simples e já deve ter respostas aqui para tal ... Obrigado rapa!